# How to reverse Photoshop cropping back to older behavior (non-ratio locked)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

The newest photoshop requires you to press shift while drag to remove the ratio lock, which is not the behavior I desire. Can I untick a setting to revert it back to the old behavior?

Answer (score 1):

It's in Preferences>General. Check the "Use Legacy Free Transform" box. Hope it helps! https://youtu.be/iPjGk3o2V28 [image: Screenshot of General Settings]

Comment: I don't have this option, screenshot: https://imgur.com/cXW20AW